# Extra select when persisting an entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa

When i try to save a entity

```
@Autowired
private GenericDao<ProfileRoles, Integer> gProfileRolesDao;
...
gProfileRolesDao.create(new ProfileRoles(new Profile(idProfile), new Role(role)));
```

With `create`

```
@Repository
public class GenericDao<T, PK extends Serializable>  {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;
    ...
    public T create(T t) {
        this.entityManager.persist(t);
        return t;
    }
```

And `ProfileRoles` entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="profile_roles")
public class ProfileRoles {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "profile")
    private Profile profile;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "role")
    private Role role;
```

Everything is fine but i get an extra select

```
Hibernate: select role_.id, role_.label as label2_22_ from role role_ where role_.id=?
Hibernate: insert into profile_roles (profile, role) values (?, ?)
```

How can I optimize this ?

Comment: Please post the entities as well

Comment: @crizzis done ;)

Comment: Huh, that's strange... unless there's some essential part of the code you haven't posted, the code should not be working at all, since you are assigning a completely new `Role` to `ProfileRoles`, and you haven't defined any cascading rules. Could you also post the code surrounding the call to `gProfileRoleDao.create()`? Also, does the `ProfileRoles` have a 'standard' constructor implementation or is there something more going on inside?

Comment: `gProfileRolesDao.create(new ProfileRoles(new Profile(idProfile), role));`

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a discussion than an answer at this stage, but need more than a comment for the code sample...

A quick test, assigning a `new Role(existingRoleId)` to the `ProfileRole` worked fine, with no extra select against the `role` table.

The extra select could point to something saving or merging the `role`.  After the select Hibernate then finds no changes that need to be updated back to the database.

A straightforward way to trace what is selecting for the role would be a `@PostLoad` method on `Role`.  For example, it could dump the current stack trace:

```
@PostLoad
public void postLoad() {
    new Exception("Post-load trace stack").printStackTrace();
}
```

With luck this will provide a lead.

Answer (score 0):

In general, to avoid extra selects when creating an entity that has many-to-one associated entities, first, you should obtain references for them.

So in your case you should take references of `Profile` and `Role` (if you don't have them already), and then create `ProfileRoles` with them, for example:

```java
// begin transaction
Profile profile = entityManager.getReference(Profile.class, profileId);
Role role = entityManager.getReference(Role.class, roleId);
entityManager.persist(new ProfileRoles(profile, role))
// commit
```

More info: [How do find and getReference EntityManager methods work when using JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/entitymanager-find-getreference-jpa/)